# Set status bar color relative to MaterialToolbar?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to set my status bar color to be the same as a given MaterialToolbar I have in my activity.

I am using switch cases consisting of `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES` & `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:` to set the application to Day or NightMode and I would like to have my statusbar match.

on YES I utilize `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` to take my activity out of NightMode & `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` to set NightMode. It is basically a switch.

My MaterialToolbar alternates between the ColorPrimary I have it set on default and it's NightMode equivalent. My question is, how can I get my statusbar to change to the same colors, preferably as a style. As I have it set to: `<item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/isLightTheme</item>` for the time being.

If it is not possible through styles, how would I set it programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution, simply. add a -night qualifier to a new resource folder. Replace required information between the modes there.

For example in my case, StatusbarColor can be changed between day and night style values.